# How edit attributes in dimension element of IBM Сognos with REST API

Tags: rest, cognos

I am creating new dimension element in IBM Cognos via REST API. I need to change the attributes of these elements. How can this be done via the REST api?

[create element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMvdn.png)

Comment: Can you give an example?  Might be a definition/language issue/
Not sure what you mean by a new dimension, unless you are referring to the data layer and adding to a Framework manager model

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Attributes are stored as cubes cells. Here's an example of setting attributes for my example.

POST: https://localhost:10005/api/v1/Cubes('%7DElementAttributes_Cars')/tm1.Update

BODY:

```
[{
  "Cells": [
    {
      "Tuple@odata.bind": [
        "Dimensions('}ElementAttributes_Cars')/Hierarchies('}ElementAttributes_Cars')/Elements('Caption')",
        "Dimensions('Cars')/Hierarchies('Cars')/Elements('000007')"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Value": "Chevrolet Niva 2015"
}]
```